# Can't post json in a Mojo::UserAgent request

Tags: perl, mojolicious, mojo

I can't get the following `Mojo::UserAgent` call to post JSON to the server:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $ua=Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $json = $ua->post("localhost:6767" => {} => json =>{ val=>10 })->res->json;
```

Using a fake debug server on the other side with `nc -l 6767` gives the following output:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mojolicious (Perl)
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:6767
```

It's not just the `json` method, the `form`, and the whole Transactor seems to be broken on 2 of my machines. From the docs:

```
perl -MMojo::UserAgent::Transactor -E 'say Mojo::UserAgent::Transactor->new->tx(PUT => "http://kraih.com" => json => {a => "b"})->req->to_string;'
PUT / HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 4
Host: kraih.com

json
```

Hard to believe my eyes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are all of your boxes using Mojolicious 3.85 or greater? The UA `form`/`json` generators are very new, only since [3.85 or 2013-02-13](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/Changes#L44).

Also you might try removing the empty hashref (which would be for extra headers), unless there is some reason to have it there.

Comment: That was it! I could swear I had upgraded Mojolicious during trial-and-error. Went back and only now saw the cpanm install was failing due to directory permissions... The empty hashref was not an issue.

Comment: +1 , My mojo version was outdated as well, and I too was wondering what I was doing wrong.